# Highcharts scatter chart legend toggle running slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm working on a scatter chart with highcharts. The chart renders just fine, but when I click on the legend to toggle any one of the series, the whole chart becomes very slow. It works on chrome (takes a good 15 seconds to load), but on safari, it times out. If I switch my 'type' to line, the legend toggle becomes nice and swift again. So, is there something about the highcharts scatter chart that I need to look into? FYI I also tried the booster on the highcharts API, but it doesn't work for me.
This is the code I use in the legend:

```
legend: {
        width: 0,
        enabled: true,
        itemStyle: {
                'cursor': 'pointer'
            }
    }
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adway/gv7a6ngg/17/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling animations made it toggle quickly for me.

```
options.chart.animation = false;
```